# Как остановить распространение события на кастомной кнопке на тач устройствах?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Добавил кастомную кнопку для закрытия карты. С кликом мышкой все ок, когда включаю в DevTools эмуляцию сотового ( и на реальных устройствах тоже ) событие проскакивает на блоки под картой.

В примере ниже в режиме эмуляции сотового, открываем карту, тапаем Закрыть, получаем смену цвета квадрата под картой.

```js
const POINTS = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Аптека1", "clusterCaption": "Аптека11", "hintContent": "Аптека111", "iconCaption": "Аптека1111"}, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Аптека2", "clusterCaption": "Аптека22", "hintContent": "Аптека222", "iconCaption": "Аптека2222"}, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Аптека3", "clusterCaption": "Аптека33", "hintContent": "Аптека333", "iconCaption": "Аптека3333"}, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption"}},
    ]
}
let map;

toggle.onclick = e => e.target.classList.toggle('bg-green');

function showMap() {
    holder.classList.remove('dn');
    map.container.fitToViewport();
}

function close() {
    holder.classList.add('dn');
}

function addCloseButton() {
  const closeButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
          data: {
              content: "Закрыть",
          },
          options: {
              selectOnClick: false,
          },
  });
  closeButton.events.add('click', close);
  map.controls.add(closeButton, { float: 'right' });
}

function addPoints(points) {
  const BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(`
    <div class="pb5">
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>
      <div class="pa3">{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>   
    </div>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 w-100 bg-white pa2 cf tr">
      <div class="ymaps-separator"></div>
      <button id="choose-point-button" class="ba br2 b--blue pa2 bg-blue white">Выбрать</button>
    </div>
    `, {

    build: function () {
      BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
      const button = document.getElementById('choose-point-button');
      button.addEventListener('click', this.onChooserClick);
    },

    clear: function () {
      const button = document.getElementById('choose-point-button');
      button.removeEventListener('click', this.onChooserClick);
      BalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
    },

    onChooserClick: function (e) {
      alert('Объект на карте выбран.');
    }
  });

  const objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    gridSize: 32,
    clusterIconLayout: "default#pieChart",
    geoObjectBalloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayout,
    clusterBalloonContentLayout: "cluster#balloonCarousel",
    balloonItemContentLayout: BalloonContentLayout,
  });
  map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

  objectManager.add(points);

  const bounds = objectManager.getBounds();
  map.setBounds(bounds, { checkZoomRange: true });
}

function init() {
    btn.onclick = showMap;
    map = new ymaps.Map('holder', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: ['geolocationControl', 'zoomControl', 'searchControl'],
    }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity,
    });

    addCloseButton();
    addPoints(POINTS);
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
.ymaps-separator {
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 1px;
}
.ymaps-separator:after, .ymaps-separator:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
}
.ymaps-separator:after {
  right: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(0,#ccc),color-stop(100%,#fff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#ccc 0,#fff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#ccc 0,#fff 100%);
}
.ymaps-separator:before {
  left: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(0,#fff),color-stop(100%,#ccc));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#fff 0,#ccc 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#fff 0,#ccc 100%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.7.0/css/tachyons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="toggle" class="h5 w5 pa5 bg-red absolute right-0 tc pointer">
  Меняю цвет по клику
</div>
<button id="btn" class="ba br3 ma4 pa2 pointer">Показать карту</button>
<div id="holder" class="dn absolute absolute--fill bg-yellow"></div>
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Не могу понять почему так происходит.

Судя по тому как описано здесь [https://learn.javascript.ru/events-and-timing-depth#очередь-событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-and-timing-depth#%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9), я предполагаю, что по touchstart на кнопке "Закрыть" дополнительно генерируется событие click и далее обрабатывается отдельно.
У меня ловится только click, почему оно срабатывает если на контейнере карты сделать `holder.addEventListener.('click', e => e.stopPropagation())`.

И совсем не понятно как может влиять `holder.addEventListenter('touchstart', e => e.preventDefault())`, если добавить, то данная проблема решается, но убивается прокрутка большого контента в балуне и кастомная кнопка в балуне не нажимается (не работает на мобилке, на десктопе прокручивается и нажимается)

Comment: В [Клубе API Карт](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/kak-ostanovit-sobytie-na-kastomnoy-knopke-na-tachakh) ответили: ymapsapi
вчера, 11:08
Спасибо за подробное описание, похоже на баг на нашей стороне, посмотрим повнимательнее.

Comment: Пока в качестве костыльного решения убрал `closeButton.events.add('click', close);`, добавил `$('#map').on('click', '#button_close', close);` - работает, но не дело, конечно.